# Need a clarity on hiveconf and set command in hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, bigdata

I need some clarity on using these variables:

```
set a=${env:ab};
${hiveconf:a}
```

What is the use of these variables and under which environment?

Answer (score 0):

You'll find some explanations here https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+VariableSubstitution

The main usage is with `--hivevar` and the ability to pass variables from the invoking application (Oozie, Shell, Java,..) to Hive statements

Comment: Thanks a lot @Harold.